# What happens if I forge a customer's signature?

Tags: forgery

So I work at a Pharmacy as a Pharmacy Technician, and it was my first day today. I got assigned to work at the drive-thru for customers picking up their prescriptions.

So our system always asks for signature of the customer after I ring up the prescription to prove that they have picked it up. 
The system asks you if the customer is at drive thru or front store. I accidentally tapped "front store" so the system asked me for the customer's digital signature and I, guiltly and doubtly tried to just do the signature for them -- WITHOUT ASKING THE CUSTOMER. I was too scared to ask them if they could sign in my computer because duh, it was drive thru and they were an old couple and I was scared they'd get mad at me. And I stupidly didn't ask my colleagues for help. I didn't know I could do the signature manually instead of digital.

Am i going to jail? I'm so scared. I haven't even started college yet. I am so anxious and mad at myself I don't know what to do. I don't want to upset my family and the store I work at.

Answer (score 3):

> Am i going to jail? I'm so scared.

No, probably not.

The details depend on jurisdiction, but normally the only crime you could be accused of would be that of forgery. However, forgery by definition requires an "intention to deceive". So my personal advice would be to come clean immediately: Go to your employer, and tell them you did not understand the checkout system and accidentally signed yourself, instead of having the customer sign. If you do that, what you did would not count as forgery, because (as you explain) you did not do it on purpose to trick someone.

Now, your boss may still decide to discipline you in some way, maybe even fire you, but that's out of your hand. If they are reasonable, they'll hopefully understand a minor mistake on the first day.

That said, it is possible your jurisdiction has special penalties for incorrectly filling out medical documents, so there may be more to it - but I doubt it. To be sure, try asking someone you know and trust who is familiar with the legal rules around medication. Or book a single consultation with a lawyer - this is not cheap (typically around $100 in the USA, or 100€ in the EU), but will give you peace of mind. You could also try asking around if there is a local initiative which offers legal help, possibly a professional organization or trade union.

Comment: All this, except that there might be intent to deceive here, if the intention was to make the system think that the customer signed. So what was signed - the customer's name? Or something like "Oops Drivethru?" But either way, no one is going to jail. Tell your immediate supervisor. It's very likely this will just go away. You deserve a dope-slap, but since we don't do that anymore you'll probably just get a reprimand.